# Can't find definition of vmmin() in R package MASS

Tags: c, r

I am going through the isoMDS calculation in the [MASS package](https://github.com/cran/MASS/). IsoMDS calls the c function VR_mds_dovm in src/MASS.c, then vmmin() is called at line 269 but I can't find the definition of that function.

I tried searching "vmmin" on the whole repo but the only result was the line where it is called. I tried googling "R MASS vmmin definition" but did not get any relevant results.

Comment: I have practically zero knowledge on C (coming from the R tag), but I would suggest to search for that function in relation to the C libraries loaded in that script (src/MASS.c)

Comment: Did you see this? https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/a-question-about-optim-R-and-optim-c-in-R-td4693690.html This suggests that the original vmmin code was in Pascal and then machine-translated to C many years ago. Perhaps look at the relevant Pascal code on netlib.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function is not from `MASS`, it has to come from one of the linked libraries. Indeed, `vmmin` is a function from R's C API used for optimization; here the [declaration](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/70bceab687226dd0dd2b08331dc726afd522b07a/src/include/R_ext/Applic.h#L68) and
[definition](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/appl/optim.c#L114).